# What are the options for serializing objects over 4 Gigabytes in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, serialization

We use Python pretty heavily here where I am, and it's Python 2.7.

We are serializing NumPy arrays of over 4 gigabytes (meaning, the amount of bytes is over 4 Gb, the data itself may be 1 gigasample of floats or something), and Python 2.7 does NOT support Pickling of objects like that over 4 Gb.  It's easier to show with strings (as part of pickling a NumPy array, pickle actually uses a string):

```
>>> huge_string = "*" * (2**33)  # 8 Gig
>>> import cPickle
>>> a = cPickle.dumps(huge_string, 2)
'\x80\x02U\x00q\x01.'
>>> print len(a)
6
```

The string is definitely NOT over 8 Gig.

I know that Python 3.4 and above will support this.
   https://bugs.python.org/issue11564

My two questions:

1. Is the Python community going to backport the BININT8 solution from Python 3.4/Python 3.5 to Python 2.7?  (It doesn't seem to be in Python 2.7.10 on Fedora 22)
2. Are there other ways to serialize in Python large NumPy arrays?

Comment: Is this NumPy-specific? [NumPy has its own serialization format](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) that may be better for your use case.

Comment: Numpy is a problem, but large strings are something else we battle.  What is NumPy's serialization format?

Comment: HDF5 is another excellent option for storing large numeric datasets - take a look at [h5py](http://www.h5py.org) or [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out.  I'll try to collect and try all recommendations here.

Comment: @rts1: NumPy's serialization format is `.npy`, as documented [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/neps/npy-format.html) and read/written by `numpy.save` and `numpy.load`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for responding.

There seem to be three alternatives (I'd still like to hear if the Python community is going to backport the Python 3.x solution to Python 2.7):

1. [NumPy has it's own serialization](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) (thanks user2367112)
2. [HDF5](http://www.h5py.org/)                             (thanks ali_m)
3. [PicklingTools OC Serialization](http://www.picklingtools.com/html/faq.html#python-c-extension-modules-new-as-of-picklingtools-1-6-0-and-1-3-3)   (work buddy)

We ended up using PicklingTools OC.  Thanks to everyone for responding!